# Empty response always received from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX request continuously to check whether any updates have been made or not. It is working fine, except that for every request the function sends to the PHP file, an empty string is being loaded and it is being appended unnecessarily. The document is growing in size with no data. I tried keeping the `if` loop but its not working for some reason.

```
<script>
    function storyupdater(id) {
        var x = id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "storysource.php",
            data: { flag1: "update", flag2 : "" + x },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result) { 
                    $('#storyload').append(result);
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                setTimeout(storyupdater(x), 5000);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked in the console to ensure the response is empty? What response are you expecting? What is the code in `storysource.php`? We need more detail to help you.

Comment: `result.trim()`. Or try to debug your success callback to see the actual value of result. It is obviously not empty string.

Comment: `setTimeout` code seems a bit off, you are cakkung the storyupdater immediately and after 5000ms it will call the callback on the `storyupdater`. I think what you want is: `setTimeout(function() {storyupdater(x); }, 5000);`

Comment: As `voigtan` rightly points out, you are executing the `storyupdater` immediately, then waiting 5 seconds then doing *nothing*! You need to fix that first as it currently runs again immediately after it completes the post.